# Is there a right click event on vue-good-table rows to show a context menu?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-good-table

According to what I see in [`vue-good-table documentationn`](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/configuration/table-events.html#on-row-click) there's no `right-click` event exist, only click, dbl-click, mouseEnter..

I need to have a *context-menu* opened on `right-click` for each row.
Do someone have any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Custom row template`](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/#custom-row-template) and add `@contextmenu` event as follows:

```
<vue-good-table :columns="columns" :rows="rows">
  <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">

      <div @contextmenu.prevent="openMenu($event,props.row)" >
           {{props.formattedRow[props.column.field]}}
       </div> 

  </template>
</vue-good-table>
```

for more clarification check  this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/op7prxq6z)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was exactly what I was looking for..
And great

Comment: .. And great code example too !
**one more question** - in your example I saw that if you right-click very close to the border of the row you get the default right-click menu , how can i hide it ?

Comment: that `div` element should have full width and height and no padding inside the `td` element